# Create multidimensional data array based on filename in numpy

Tags: python, multidimensional-array

All, new to python and stack overflow I have files in the form 
A_50C_100mA_0,5V and A_45C_80mA_0,7V so on where basically three variables differ C the mA and the V
What is the best way to read these files in python so that I can eventually plot all data with 45C_100mA with diff Vs or any combo say all C for given mA and V.

I was thinking of a (TxmAxV) multidimensional array. But too many for loops in the way I am thinking, Any pythonic way to do this? I would eventually like to not just plot these data but be able to manipulate them with numpy functions like smoothen etc.

Please help

Comment: What's the content of the files?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question is vague so here is just a basic snippet (that assumes you have a file containing lines with the data you mention) that might get you started:

```
file_contents = """A_50C_100mA_0,5V
A_45C_80mA_0,7V"""

data = []
for line in file_contents.split("\n"):
    data.append( line.split("_") )

for row in data:
    if row[1] == "45C":
        print( " ".join(row) )
```

spits out

```
A 45C 80mA 0,7V
```

Comment: I am Sorry for being vague.

Comment: I am sorry for being vague. The filename is 50C_100mA_0,5V.txt the values in front of C,mA and V changes. There numerous such filenames eg, 40C_80mA_1,0V.txt etc. Each file has two columns of data in X Y format, I want to be able to read this data into a multidmensional array such as [T][mA][V].x and  [T][mA][V].y Where the T mA and C are gotten from there filenames. I want to be able to eventually plot sat [50C][100mA][all V].x Vs [50C][100mA][all V].y  and then also be able to plot [allC][100mA][1,0V].x Vs  [allC][100mA][1,0V].y

Comment: @Arun Please put this info in your question instead, add some real data, format it nicely and show what code you've got so far.

Comment: Thanks handle.. I think I figured this one out. Better framed queries in the future :)